# Rename same column of different files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am writing a code in python. I have create a output csv file by merging multiple same name files. Now i want to plot it. But I am facing a problem during plotting is that the column I required for plot have different name for different output file. My code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
if df.columns[1] == 'User Time[0]':
  df.rename(columns = {'User Time[0]' : 'User Time'})
elif df.columns[1] == 'User Time[0]':
  df.rename(columns = {'User Time[1]' : 'User Time'})
elif df.columns[1] == 'User Time[0]':
  df.rename(columns = {'User Time[2]' : 'User Time'})
else:
  df.columns[1] == 'User Time'
df.plot(x='User Time', y='GDOP[2]', ax=ax, legend=False)

plt.ylim([0.0, 20.0])
plt.show()
```

As in the code I want the second column name be 'User Time'.
help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with below code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
clm = list(df.columns)
clm[1] = 'User Time'
df.columns = clm

df.plot(x='User Time', y='GDOP[2]', ax=ax, legend=False)

plt.ylim([0.0, 20.0])
plt.show()
```